# $f(x)$ is monotonic , positive, unbounded function then $\int_{0} ^{\infty } f(x)\sin(x)dx$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The question came from my try to show that:
$\int_{0} ^{\infty } (x^2+1)^n\sin(x)dx$ does not exist $\forall n \ge 1$.

Using Binomial method one gets, $\int_{0} ^{\infty } (b_1x^{2n} + b_2x^{2n-2} + ... + b_nx^{0})\sin(x)$ when $b_n$ are the binomial coefficients.

I showed by induction that $\int_{0} ^{\infty } x^nsin(x)$ does not exists **in the broad sense**.  Yet I didn't succeed to prove that the sum of all those limits (using integral additivity) doesn't exists. (When in general sum of $\lim$ expressions which doesn't exist - might exist, for example $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)$).

So the more **particular question**, how to prove that the sum of those integrals doesn't exist?

This question lead me to try and prove a more general claim as mentioned in the title , cause my intuition tells my that it is generally true, when $f(x)$ is unbounded , positive and monotone the the integral $\int_{0} ^{\infty } f(x)\sin(x)dx$ should not exist **in the broad sense (neither finite nor infinite)**. 
Unfortunately I didn't succeed in proving it. Is there a counter example? 
otherwise if it's true can one use weaker conditions for $f(x)$ for the claim to hold?

(If needed I am familiar with Lebesgue integration and basic real analysis)

Comment: Do you understand $\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\sin{x}\,dx$ as a Lebesgue integral or an improper Riemann integral?

Comment: @user539887 as an improper Riemann integral

Comment: I deleted my previous answer because it refered to Lebesgue integration. However, I wonder if the lemma I wrote still holds for improper Riemann integrals, i.e. if $g$ is non-integrable on $(0,\infty)$ (while being integrable on $(0,a)$ for all $a>0$) in  the improper Riemann sense and $f\geq \varepsilon > 0$ then $fg$ is non-integrable. Intuitively, this seems to hold to me. If that is the case, then your claim is true even without the unboundedness assumption.

Answer (score 2):

The improper integral converges if and only if the Cauchy criterion is satisfied, that is for any $\epsilon> 0$ there exists $K > 0$ such that for all $c_2 > c_1 > K$

$$\left| \int_{c_1}^{c_2} f(x) \sin x \, dx \right| < \epsilon.$$

Taking $c_1 = \pi/4 +2n\pi$ and $c_2 = 3\pi/4 +2n\pi$, we get when $f$ is increasing

$$\left| \int_{\pi/4 +2n\pi}^{3 \pi/4 + 2n\pi} f(x) \sin x \, dx \right| \geqslant f(\pi/4) \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}},$$

violating the Cauchy criterion.

Of course, there are weaker conditions for the improper integral to not exist. For example, $f$ could be bounded as $0 < m \leqslant f(x) \leqslant M$. If, however, $f$ is positive and monotonically decreasing with $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, then the improper integral exists by the Dirichlet test.

Comment: Notice that the OP asked about the **nonexistence** of the improper Riemann integral, not the **non-convergence**.  The case that $\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\sin{x}\,dx=\infty$ (or $-\infty$) should be excluded (and in that case the Cauchy criterion is irrelevant).

Comment: The improper Riemann integral $\int_a^\infty g(x) \, dx$ exists if $\lim_{c \to +\infty} \int_a^c g(x) \, dx$ exists (i.e. a finite limit exists) (Apostol definition 10.32).  The Cauchy criterion is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: So, if the OP considers "improper integral converges" and "improper integral exists" synonyms (I, for my part, do not), that's O.K.

Comment: @user539887: Then you would also disagree with Definition 32.3 in The Elements of Real Analysis by Bartle and Theorem 32.5 in the same book which states that the improper integral "exists" if and only if the Cauchy criterion is satisfied.  Are you thinking about the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: I mean improper Riemann integral. To me, $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert x\rvert\,dx$ exists (and is equal to $\infty$), and $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx$ does not. In order to avoid such misunderstandings, I prefer to use the expression "improper integral ... is convergent" (then everyone has to understand that the limit is a real number).

Comment: @RRL Thanks a lot for your answer, but as user539887 said, I am searching for a proof such that the improper integral doesn't exist also in the broad sense (neither finite nor infinite).

Comment: So now you want to prove that $\liminf_{c \to \infty}\int_0^c f(x) \sin x \, dx \neq \limsup_{c \to \infty} \int_0^c f(x) \sin x \, dx$ under these conditions.  I suspect it does not. For example $\int_0^c x \sin x \, dx = \sin c - c \cos c$.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma**. Let $f,g:(a,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann-integrable on $(a,b)$ for all $b>a$. Suppose further that $g$ is non-integrable on $(a,\infty)$ in the improper Riemann sense and that $f\geq \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Then $fg$ is non-integrable on $(a,\infty)$ as well.

**Proof.** Since $\lim_{b\to \infty}\int_{a}^bg(x)dx$ does not exist, there exists a $\varepsilon'>0$ and a sequence $\left\{b_k\right\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $b_k\to \infty$ such that $\left|\int_{a}^{b_{k}}g(x)dx\right|\geq \varepsilon'$. Hence
$$\left|\int_{a}^{b_k}f(x)g(x)dx\right|\geq \varepsilon\left|\int_{a}^{b_k}g(x)dx\right|\geq \varepsilon \varepsilon',\qquad \forall k\in \mathbb{N} $$
Thus $\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{a}^{b_k}f(x)g(x)dx$ does not exist, and hence neither does $\lim_{b\to \infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx$.

Apply the previous result to $g(x)=\sin(x)$, which is non-integrable on $(a,\infty)$ for all $a>0$. If $f$ is increasing and positive, then for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an $a>0$ such that $f(x)\geq \varepsilon$ on $(a,\infty)$. Unboundedness of $f$ is actually not needed.

EDIT: I adapted my proof to improper Riemann integrals.

Comment: Notice that the OP's intent could be to ask whether $\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\sin{x}\,dx$ does not exist **considered as an improper Riemann integral**. In such a case your answer is not complete.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about improper Riemann integrals. In that case, you can have $g$ integrable but $g^+$ and $g_-$ not integrable. Example: $g(x)=\sin x/x$.

Comment: Well, I used the Lebesgue integral because OP said he/she is familiar with it. But I agree with your remarks, this answer is not appropriate for improper Riemann integrals.

Answer (score 1):

For the improper integral to exist, we need in particular that
$$a_n:=\int_0^{n\pi}f(x)\sin x\,\mathrm dx $$
converges, in oparticular, is a Cauchy sequence. However,
$$ a_{2n+1}-a_{2n}=\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}f(x)\sin x\,\mathrm dx\ge \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}f(2n\pi)\sin x\,\mathrm dx=2f(2n\pi)$$
does not tend to $0$.

Comment: See my comment below RRL's answer.